# How to pass touch event to other views only when touchtype is finger?

Tags: ios, swift, touches

I have a subview over my view and i want this subview only to recognize pencil touch types. Every time the touch type is a finger i want it to be recognized by the parent view. Currently i am using the function shown below. The problem here is that the UIEvent has no touches so its not possible to check if it is a finger or pencil touch.

```
override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Comment: Why not override `touchesBegan|Moved|Ended`?

Comment: because "point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool" is called before the touchesbegan function

Answer (score 2):

#### Update

One option would be disabling user interaction on the bottom view, and in the top view implementing:

```
func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent)
func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent)
func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent)
```

In these functions, you can check the type with `touches.first?.type`, and you can check the view with `touches.first?.view`, and if they satisfy your criteria you can call `touchesBegan/Moved/Ended` on the bottom view.

#### What it said before:

Use these three methods:

```
func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent)
func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent)
func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent)
```

You can check they type with touches.first?.type, and you can check the view with touches.first?.view.

You could forward the touches by calling `touchesBegan/Moved/Ended` on the view underneath.

Comment: Thats a good solution but my view is a UIScrollview. So when i pass tocuhesMoved nothing happpens ...

Comment: That's a complicated problem (UIScrollView with touchesMoved). Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259005/uiscrollview-with-touchesmoved-not-called) could help?

Comment: Is there maybe a way that all my views detect touches and not only one ?

Comment: ScrollViews gobble up touches kind of obnoxiously. I think the solution I linked to in my last comment would help. An alternative (which I would do) is to have a simple view on top of the two views that manages all touches and forwards them to the appropriate view.